# Topic publish/subscribe problem after running dist-upgrade on ROS Hydro

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, rostopic--pub, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After running apt-get dist-upgrade on **ROS Hydro**, simulated robot is not responding to published messages. The simulator is running perfectly. The code/topics are working fine on Turtle-bot (hardware) i.e. *publishing and subscribing*.

`rosdep --version: 0.10.24`

***export | grep ROS*** gives us this:

```
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="hydro"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros"
```

We have started to work on Turtlebot and new to ROS. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109096/topic-publish/subscribe-problem-after-running-dist-upgrade-on-ros-hydro/) by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I figured out the solution to my problem.
The thing is, after having an `apt-get dist-upgrade` my gazebo simulator was upgraded to `gazebo 2.1` (previously it was `gazebo 1.9` the stable version). It looks like the newer version is having some problems with `hydro`.

I had to uninstall the new version of gazebo i.e v2.1 by `apt-get remove gazebo-current`.
After that I installed the earlier version i.e v1.9 http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.9/install and then had to run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-turtlebot-simulator
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

And it started publishing and subscribing again.

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [Safeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9456/safeer/) with karma: 66 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1